# How to prevent window.onbeforeunload function in ajax response using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using java-script `window.onbeforeunload` function to show an alert to user whenever user tries to leave the page without submitting the data. This functionality is working fine.

I facing problem, while ajax response received from server page and placed in success callback function and then i reload that window page using `window.location.href` functionality

`window.location.href=baseurl+'index.php/functionname/'+arg_id;`

While page reloading into another page it shown that dialog box section
Here my ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: baseurl+"index.php/sample/samplefunction",
 data: {"demo_detail":sse,'demo_detail':pro},
 success:function(data) {
 if(data) {
    window.location.href=baseurl+'index.php/functionname/'+arg_id; 
    }
 }
});
```

Here my working `window.onbeforeunload` functionality

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
  }
```

How to prevent for  `window.onbeforeunload` function in `ajax response` using  **javascript**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off the handler in the AJAX callback:

```
 if(data) {
    window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
    window.location.href=baseurl+'index.php/functionname/'+arg_id; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Global variable as follows:

```
var confirm = true;
```

In your ajax response set confirm to false as follows:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: baseurl+"index.php/sample/samplefunction",
 data: {"demo_detail":sse,'demo_detail':pro},
 success:function(data) {
  if(data) {
     confirm = false;
     window.location.href=baseurl+'index.php/functionname/'+arg_id; 
  }
 }
});
```

In your "comfirmExit()" function, heck if confirm is try, then only alert the waring to the user.

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
   if(confirm)
     return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
   else
     return;
}
```